# Ionic View app doesn't appear for install in portugal app store for iOS device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm building an app using Ionic 3 and would like to share it with my client to test them through "Ionic View" app using the "Ionic Pro Cloud Service", but when I find for this "Ionic View" at Portugal's app store, we not find it.

Anyone had this problem? Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

researching the reasons why this senseless problem was occurring, I found an official publication that justifies. The APP is outside of the "App Store", not only in Portugal, but in all places.

https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002722493